# How to input an incrementing value to a string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a bunch of links that I want to be sent to a function. I don't want to hardcode them I want them in an array and each time it will call the next link. I am quite new to Java, not quite sure how to do this, but in my C++/C# experience it looked something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        String[] imageURLArray = new String[]{
                "http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg",
                "http://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/a-mc-random-35.jpg?w=500&h=375",
                "http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg",
                "http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg",
                "http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg",
                "http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg",
        };

        final SpinnerModel sched = new SpinnerModel();

          /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
           sched.setCourseName("Company "+i);
           sched.setImage("image"+i);
           sched.setCourseShortDesc(imageURLArray[i]); //where my question lies
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you need an Iterator.

Instead of having a static array like you already have you need to create a

```
List<String> imageURLArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then add each of the strings by doing

```
imageURLArray.add("http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg");
```

for all the strings that you want.
Then create your Iterator by doing

```
Iterator<String> iter = imageURLArray.iterator();
```

And then create your loop (like in your example) like the following:

```
final SpinnerModel sched = new SpinnerModel();
/******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
for(int i = 0; iter.hasNext(); i++) {
    sched.setCourseName("Company "+i);
    sched.setImage("image"+i);
    sched.setCourseShortDesc(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: YES i remember Iterator being discussed in class, did not understand it until now. Thank you

Comment: When implementing this, it returns with the last element in the array for each item in the spinner

Comment: Try moving the SpinnerModel sched declaration inside the for-loop